# How to query with Loopback JS model string parameter contains in regexp array?

Tags: loopbackjs

I tried to query Loopback js Model using "inq" (mongo $in) syntax

like this:

`let itemNames = [/test/i, /test2/i];
app.models.skill.find({where: {name: {inq: itemNames}}}, ....`

But loopback is changing regexp to strings.
loopback sends strings like

`{ name: { $in: [ "/test/i", "/test2/i" ] } }`

expected to work like described here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#use-the-in-operator-with-a-regular-expression

Can you suggest a fix or a workaround for this (but I can't patch loopback itself it is a business requirement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loopback accepted my changes, 
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/pull/1279

so it should be possible to use regexps like in mongo.

Answer (score 0):

You may create `inq` item like this:

```js
let itemNames = [new RegExp('/test/i'), new RegExp('/test2/i')];
```

It worked for me.